# In websocket how does server identify a client's webserver

Tags: websocket

If I am not wrong, to have a push technology the client ( say browser ) also needs to run a small web server which is listening on some port ( say ijetty runs on 8080 ). Now when the actual server comes to know about any event, it sends the event to client. This way there is no PULL mechanism involved at all. Is this right ? OR there is a persistent connection involved and server sends the data on that connection whenever the event happens. My question is : in the former case ( if it is true ), how does server know about client's IP ?

Comment: How to do that. I don't know. Please let me know.

Comment: Go to your profile, you will see a list of all your questions.. go to each question and mark the good answer to each one of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebSockets working with socket based on TCP connection, basically the client make a request for connection to the server with a challenge, websocket version, ip and more data, then the server decrypts the challenge and return his result back to the client, this process called Handshake.

If the handshake is approved, the connection is made, the socket connection remains open between the client and the server, heartbeats will be sent from the server to the client like a ping to check if the connection is still open.

read this wiki to find out more:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket